Not able to ssh to server with ubuntu user getting black screen and not able to perform any command
I'm encountering an issue with the server running Ubuntu 20.04 hosted on AWS cloud. The instance is configured with t3a.2xlarge specifications. Initially, I encountered an error with npm, which prompted me to make some changes. However, following these changes, I'm unable to SSH to the server using the 'ubuntu' user. Surprisingly, I can still SSH using the 'jenkins' user and switch to the root user. Could someone assist me with this?

Could you elaborate on the changes you made?

These kinds of symptoms are usually a result of errors in the user's login shell initialization file(s) i.e. ~/.profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.bashrc

Logs for failed authentication are available in /var/log/auth.log. Follow its contents when you try to connect wit the Ubuntu user to see what it says. sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
